# Вместо ? поставить одно из 2 значений

Tags: java

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(WHERE_1_1);
Boolean b = isActive.getIsActive();
```

b может быть null, true и false

```
    if (b != null) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(b)) {
```

Boolean.TRUE.equals(b) ругается Сонар если поставить if(b)

```
            sb.append(" and is_active = true");
        } else {
            sb.append(" and is_active = false");
        }
    }
```

Как можно сделать через?

```
" and is_active = ? "
```

и нужное подставить

Comment: У ответов на Ваши вопросы слева есть значок "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (b != null)
  sb.append(" and is_active = " + b? "true" : "false");
```

---

```
if (b != null)
  sb.append(" and is_active = " + b.toString());
```